# Akaike criterion (AIC) for quasi-Poisson models

Tags: r, model, glm, poisson

I run quasi-Poisson glm models in R and I want to compute AIC criterion. I run the code below but I am not sure if it is correct. Also, I find weird the fact that the AIC decreases while degrees of freedom increase.

```r
fqaic <- function(model) {
  loglik <- sum(dpois(model$y, model$fitted.values, log = TRUE))
  phi <- summary(model)$dispersion
  qaic <- -2*loglik + 2*summary(model)$df[3]*phi
  return(qaic)
}
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Can you please add a (minimal) data example to make your code reproducible? Please see stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

There are some notes [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bbmle/vignettes/quasi.pdf), indicating that among other things that there are existing methods for computing qAIC in the `bbmle`, `AICcmodavg`, and `MuMIn` packages.  The correct formula for qAIC is

```
-2 * logLik/dispersion + 2 * df
```